# Equivalent of MYSQL 'SELECT INTO' in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a temporary table. Call it `table1`. I want to copy every row in `table1` to `table2`. I believe `SELECT INTO` can do that in mysql.

Now I'm wondering how I can accomplish this with cakephp2.4.

Comment: Please share the code you have already tried.

Comment: You can use raw SQL in CakePHP if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->loadModel('Table1');
    $find_new=$this->Table1->find('all');
    $this->set('find_new', $find_new);
    foreach($find_new as $find_new):
    $this->Tabel2->create();
    $this->request->data['Table2']['field1']=$find_new['Table1']['field1'];
    $this->request->data['Table2']['field2']=$find_new['Table1']['field2'];
    $this->request->data['Table2']['field3']=$find_new['Table1']['field3'];
    $this->Table2->save($this->request->data);
    endforeach;
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
```